# Would it be off topic to make a question thread about pictures of the software development process?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I want to post the following question but I'm worried it will be closed as off topic:

Title: Great software development pictures

[This](http://www.designandco.net/) design company I know absolutely nothing about has on their website a beautiful picture of people actively engaged in the design process. I'm interested in collecting similar pictures which relate to the software development process and software development places. What great pictures related to software development have you seen?

For example, FogCreek has this picture on their site:

[image]

**EDIT:**

What if I changed the question to relate only to software development places - pictures of where software development happens?

Comment: This is not on topic. it is a shopping list.

Comment: It... *is* sorta off-topic. Also, you don't want to see what it looks like when I'm working, and I'd *have* to force you to if you asked that.

Comment: That guy's not a programmer. I smell a modeling agency. Who eats bananas while programming with one hand? Joel's [Wasabi](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/09/01b.html) would crash, or something.

Comment: FogCreek is a front for a banana modelling agency?!

Comment: First all the pictures of Joel's office are real! It means that the developer in the picture works there! And the environment there is very pleasant!

Comment: Sure. And Wasabi is a Japanese condiment.

Comment: @Robert Harvey What does that means?

Comment: It's a failed attempt at sarcasm.  See here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/09/01b.html

Comment: Even if you were to collect such pictures what would you do with them? You can't use them publicly as they're copyright the photographer or the company.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that would not be on-topic. Or, more precisely, it would not be constructive.

For one, it's a question where every answer is equally valid. For another, it's kind of a "getting to know you" question.

Both of those are explicitly discouraged in the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq).